# Angular 2: Update the iframe src when router url gets change

Tags: angular, iframe

App has a top-bar with 3 dashboard buttons on it. Every link opens up a new dashboard on the page via iframe.

**app.component.html**

```html
<md-toolbar class="toolbar">
  <span>Dashboardds</span>
  <span class="spacer"></span>
  <button md-button  [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'first']"  id="first" class="top-link">First</button>
  <button md-button  [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'second']"  id="second" class="top-link">Second</button>
  <button md-button  [routerLink]="['/dashboard', 'third']"  id="third" class="top-link">Third</button>
</md-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
{path: 'dashboard/:id', component: DashboardComponent},
{path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard/first', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard/first', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Dashboard component is very straightforward. It has 3 urls and 1 iframe.

**dashboard.component.html**

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
dashboardUrl: SafeUrl;
  first_url: string = "first url of the dashboard";
  second_url:string="second url of the dashboard";
  third_url:string="third url of the dashboard";


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    //console.log("Constructor "+route.snapshot.params['id']);
    this.dashboardUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.first_south_url);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dashboardUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.first_south_url);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```js
<iframe id="report-frame" frameborder="0" [src]="dashboardUrl"></iframe>
```

How can I update iframe url based on the button clicked on the topbar and  reload the iframe with new url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should subscribe in the `dashboard.component.ts` file to the `ActivatedRoute` object to get the changes in the route and update the iframe. To avoid the unsafe value error while setting the iframe destination and to keep your code clean, you should use the `DomSanitizer` within a pipe.

**safe.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'safe' })
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  transform(url) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

Also, don't forget to add `SafePipe` to the **declarations** of you AppModule.

**dashboard.component.ts**

```js
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  private dashboardUrl: string;
  private urlMap: { local: string, remote: string }[] = [
    { local: "first", remote: "http://google.com" },
    { local: "second", remote: "http://stackoverflow.com" }
    // ...
  ];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let localParam = params['id'];
      this.dashboardUrl = this.urlMap.filter(x => x.local == localParam)[0].remote;
    });
  }
}
```

**dashboard.component.html**

```js
<iframe id="report-frame" frameborder="0" [src]="dashboardUrl | safe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything on the `app.component.html` page?