# Getting queryParams for Angular app within iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, query-string

I have an angular app sitting within an iframe and I want to get a query param value using the code below.

```
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params);
    })
```

But in the console the log message is empty, however when running the app in the browser directly it will detect the query params correctly.

I feel like this must be possible, what is the correct way of getting the query params when an angular app is within an iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Iframe is an isolated environment, which means the `params` your angular app see is the params from iframe, not the host window.

The keyword for this is `iframe communication` or [`iframe activatedroute`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42873671/angular-2-update-the-iframe-src-when-router-url-gets-change), I don't have much experience working with iframe in angular so I can't give much detail here. But in general, I did work with postMessage, which works for my case.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage